# SSRS Textbox action is executed only once

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create the report that would have action link in the text box that would update the record in database. First of all I've created *datasource* with the "*Execute in single transaction*" setting on. I've created *dataset* that calls the *stored procedure* with param:
[image]
Then specified the param:
[image]
I've created the table where the last column is "Action".

In the TextBox properties, in the Action menu set to go to the same report and set param value to the one from the table:
[image]

The thing is that it's working only once and if I click on the same field again then the *procedure* is not executed. I guess that param is not set, but I am not sure.

**UPDATE:**

After some playing I see, that variable is set so the problem is not in variable. Additionally if I click on another row then this row is updated as expected. After that I can updated the first row also, so the problem is that I can't update the same row twice in a roll.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[change_salesperson_status]
    @code AS CHAR(5)
AS
    BEGIN

       INSERT INTO dbo.test VALUES (@code);
        IF (@code = 'test') RETURN 1;

        UPDATE dbo.salespersons
           SET status_code = CASE WHEN status_code = 'I' THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END
         WHERE code = @code;
    END;


GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.test
(
    a VARCHAR(200)
)
```

**UPDATE2:**
I was able to workaround this. I've added internal datetime variable with default value =NOW() this forced SSRS to refresh report every time.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, it's a guide to how I would do this but too long to put as a comment.

I've done quite a few of these reports and never had any issues. I suspect your workflow is not quite right.

What I normally do is write a dataset query that accepts parameters that update the database unless the default values are passed.
I'm not sure what you are trying to do but if we take a simple example, creating  a report called, say `myReport` which makes an employee inactive if a column is clicked then we might have a simple table

```
EmpID    EmpName    MakeInactive
  1      Dave         click
  2      Bob          click
```

The dataset would look something like this...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF @EmployeeID > 0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE myTable SET Active = 0 WHERE EmpID = @EmployeeID
        END

    SELECT EmpID, EmpName FROM myTable
```

The `myReport` report would have a single parameter `@EmployeeID` in this simple case and the default value would be `-1` so when we first run the report, no updates occur.

In the last column you would do as you have already, that is, set the action to call the same report (`myReport`) with the `@EmployeeID` parameter set to the `EmpID` from the first column.

That's all that I would do, I don't use single transactions or anything else, I just do as above and it works.

Comment: I couldn't find any difference in the description you've provided, the only thing that my param is @code and default value is 'test'. In stored procedure I have first statement that is IF (@code = 'test') RETURN 1;. However I've put logging to the statement before it and  the log was not added, so the procedure was not executed. So, from beginning: when I open report I see 'test' in the logs, then I click on the row and I see 'proper_value' there, then I click for the 2nd time I have no records there.

Comment: Can you post the stored proc code? Also, when you run it the final time, what does your parameter value show, does it show what you expect?

Comment: Updated the question